# How can I start a simple xterm.js terminal that echoes input?

Tags: javascript, electron, xtermjs

I've just started getting into `xterm.js` but I'm having some trouble going through the documentation as it doesn't seem to be written for starters nor are there any guides on doing a simple starter project.

I understand I could develop some line reading mechanism with the `Terminal.onKey()` method but I feel like I'm re-inventing the wheel.

Do you know something like a repository for a simple `xterm.js` console that would manage navigation, modifier and editing keys that would only echo the line written in it after hitting `Return`?

Thank you for your time! Hopefully I find someone who is into this too

Comment: Best starting point is prolly the demo project in the xterm repo (https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/tree/master/demo). But note - we use it for development purpose, it lacks aspects needed for production envs like proper security settings and flow control.

Comment: And for a selfcontained terminal-cmdline solution without any PTY in between, see https://github.com/wavesoft/local-echo.